# Android Softkeyboard "Done" key gone

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm making an APP and want to change the keyboard "Line Break" key into a "Done" key, But I cant use the `android:signleLine="true"` (seen here: [Done key not showing up on keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697547/done-key-not-showing-up-on-keyboard))  because the EditText isn't the last EditText in my code.

What could I use/do instead?

Thanks.

Edit
Here is my code:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:width="40dp"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textFilter"
            android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you using Startdard Key board of android of is there any other app for keyboard try in other phone with imeOptions="actionDone"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use to set the keyboard action button [imeOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Read more about imeOptions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Type)

You will also have to remove the line

```
android:digits="ABC..."
```

as imeOptions do not work well with this.

Comment: Can you please update your post to what you changed?

Comment: Same code, plus the line "android:imeOptions="actionDone""

Comment: You will also have to remove the line `android:digits="ABC..."`, imeOptions do not work well with this

Comment: What should I use instead? I need the field to accept only A-Z CapCharacters

Comment: You could use an InputFilter to allow only certain characters. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4401227/493321) is an example.

Comment: Just noticed, if I add the InputFilter, I can't use the "maxLength" atribbute?

Comment: I fixed it by adding another filter to set the maxLength, but I wanted to know WHY they don't work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this.

> By XML

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

> By Java

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

this may helps you.

Comment: try to default keypad